# DependencyProperty and DataBinding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

In WPF:

Can someone please explain the relationship between DependencyProperty and Databinding?

I have a property in my code behind I want to be the source of my databinding.
When does a DependencyProperty (or does it) come into play if I want to bind this object to textboxes on the XAML.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The target in a binding must always be a `DependencyProperty`, but any property (even plain properties) can be the source.

The problem with plain properties is that the binding will only pick up the value once and it won't change after that because change notification is missing from the plain source property.

To provide that change notification without making it a `DependencyProperty`, one can:

1. Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the class defining the property.
2. Create a *`PropertyName`*`Changed` event. (Backward compatibility.)

WPF will work better with the first choice.

Answer (score 0):

### *What is the DependencyProperty?*

The **DependencyProperty** class is one of the most important design bases hidden deep in the .Net Framework WPF.

This class is protected by `sealed` from the .NET Framework.
This property differs from the one-dimensional general property in that it not only stores field values, but also takes advantage of the various functions provided within the class.
Most importantly, there is a full foundation for data binding. You can also send notifications whenever you bind something.

[DependencyProperty](https://github.com/devncore/dependencyproperty#what-is-the-dependencyproperty)
[Wpf Xaml Binding](https://github.com/devncore/wpf-xaml-binding#datacontext-is-always-the-reference-point-for-binding)

It's already a late answer, but I'll introduce the results of my research.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28759583)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. We will revise the necessary contents by reinforcing them.