# WPF Data Binding and IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, converters

Why is it that when I use a converter in my binding expression in WPF, the value is not updated when the data is updated.

I have a simple Person data model:

```
class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My binding expression looks like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource personNameConverter}" />
```

My converter looks like this:

```
class PersonNameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Person p = value as Person;
        return p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If I bind the data without a converter it works great:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:
Just to clarify a few things, both Joel and Alan are correct regarding the INotifyPropertyChanged interface that needs to be implemented. In reality I do actually implement it but it still doesn't work.

I can't use multiple TextBlock elements because I'm trying to bind the Window Title to the full name, and the Window Title does not take a template.

Finally, it is an option to add a compound property "FullName" and bind to it, but I'm still wondering why updating does not happen when the binding uses a converter. Even when I put a break point in the converter code, the debugger just doesn't get there when an update is done to the underlying data :-(

Thanks,
Uri

Comment: Did you make a mistake in your post? Should your binding be:
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName, Converter={StaticResource personNameConverter}" />

??

Comment: Looks like I've learned a thing or two today. See my updates.

Comment: Is the Window Title a dependency property? I don't have the time to look at the moment. maybe that's why it's not updating for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**(see edits below; latest: #2)**

It isn't updating because your `Person` object is not capable of notifying anything that the value of `FirstName` or `LastName` has changed. [See this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159088/dependencyproperty-and-databinding).

And here's how you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. (**Updated, see Edit 2**)

```
using System.ComponentModel;

class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string _firstname;
    public string FirstName {
        get {
            return _firstname;
        }
        set {
            _firstname = value;
            onPropertyChanged( "FirstName", "FullName" );
        }
    }

    string _lastname;
    public string LastName {
        get {
            return _lastname;
        }
        set {
            _lastname = value;
            onPropertyChanged( "LastName", "FullName" );
        }
    }

    public string FullName {
        get {
            return _firstname + " " + _lastname;
        }
    }

    void onPropertyChanged( params string[] propertyNames ) {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if ( handler != null ) {
            foreach ( var pn in propertyNames ) {
                handler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( pn ) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

Actually, since you're after the first name and last name updating, and `Path=FirstName` and such works just fine, I don't think you'll need the converter at all. Multiple `TextBlocks` are just as valid, and can actually work better when you're localizing to a right-to-left language.

**Edit 2**

I've figured it out. It's not being notified that the properties have updated because it is binding to the object itself, not one of those properties. Even when I made `Person` a `DependencyObject` and made `FirstName` and `LastName` `DependencyProperties`, it wouldn't update.

You *will* have to use a `FullName` property, and I've update the code of the `Person` class above to reflect that. Then you can bind the `Title`. (**Note:** I've set the `Person` object as the `Window`'s `DataContext`.)

```
Title="{Binding Path=FullName, Mode=OneWay}"
```

If you're editing the names in a `TextBox` and want the name changed reflected immediately instead of when the `TextBox` loses focus, you can do this:

```
<TextBox Name="FirstNameEdit"
    Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

I know you didn't want to use a `FullName` property, but anything that would accomplish what you want would probably be a bit of a Rube Goldberg device. Such as implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` and a `Person` property on the `Window` class itself, having the `Window` listen on the `PropertyChanged` event in order to fire the `Window`'s `PropertyChanged` event, and using a relative binding like the following. You'd also have set the `Person` property before `InitializeComponent()` or fire `PropertyChanged` after setting the `Person` property so that it shows up, of course. (Otherwise it will be `null` during `InitializeComponent()` and needs to know when it's a `Person`.)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <loc:PersonNameConverter
        x:Key="conv" />
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Title>
    <Binding
        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"
        Converter="{StaticResource conv}"
        Path="Person"
        Mode="OneWay" />
</Window.Title>
```

Answer (score 14):

You can also use a MultiBinding.. Bind to the Person object, the FirstName and LastName. That way, the value gets updated as soon as FirstName or LastName throws the property changed event.

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{IMultiValueConverter goes here..}">
    <Binding />
    <Binding Path="FirstName" />
    <Binding Path="LastName" />
</MultiBinding>
```

Or if you only use the FirstName and LastName, strip the Person object from the binding to something like this:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{IMultiValueConverter goes here..}">
    <Binding Path="FirstName" />
    <Binding Path="LastName" />
</MultiBinding>
```

And the MultiValueConverter looks like this:

```
class PersonNameConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
            return values[0].ToString() + " " + values[1].ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But of course, the selected answer works as well, but a MultiBinding works more elegantly...

Comment: I agree. I'd completely forgotten about MultiBinding. And, after some thought, it really should be a ValueConverter's job (rather than Person) to format a full name because it receives a CultureInfo object.

Comment: Ahh thanks I have been trying to Hack around with IValueConverter to pass two arguments for a wile now... Didn't know about IMultiValueConverter.

Answer (score 1):

In Order for the binding to be updated, your person class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to let the binding know that the object's properties have been udpated. You can also save yourself from the extra converter by providing a fullName property.

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace INotifyPropertyChangeSample
{
    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string firstName;
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set
            {
                if (firstName != value)
                {
                    firstName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
                    OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
                }
            }
        }

        private string lastName;
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }
            set
            {
                if (lastName != value)
                {
                    lastName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
                    OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
                }
            }
        }

        public string FullName
        {
            get { return firstName + " " + lastName; }
        } 

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Your Binding will now look like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.FullName}" />
```

Comment: Adding a FullName property to the Person class solves the problem, but it's not the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't check it but can you also try the following

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=/, Converter={StaticResource personNameConverter}}" />
```

Comment: quick and simple option, THANKS!